# Filter CHANGED_AT from CRM_ORDER_READ

Tags: abap, function-module, sap-crm

I have a requirement wherein I have to filter CHANGED_AT from CRM_ORDER_READ.

I used the dynamic query as follows:

```
lr_core = cl_crm_bol_core=>get_instance( ).
lr_core->load_component_set( 'ONEORDER' ).

lr_qs ?= cl_crm_bol_dquery_service=>get_instance( 'BTQSrvOrd' ).

lr_qs->set_query_parameters( lt_param ).

lr_qs->ADD_SELECTION_PARAM( iv_attr_name = 'CHANGED_AT'

iv_sign = 'I'

iv_option = 'GT'

iv_low = '20171127000000' ).

lr_result = lr_qs->get_query_result( ).
```

But the result is null though there are entries.

I found the blogs regarding the same issue but none solved the issue. Is the query correct?

Or is there any other way to filter CHANGED_AT?

Complete Code:

```
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
 INCLUDE: ztest_rfc_incl,
           crm_object_kinds_con,
           crm_object_names_con.

  TYPES:
    BEGIN OF ty_but000,
      name_org1    TYPE bu_nameor1,
      name_org2    TYPE bu_nameor2,
      partner_guid TYPE bu_partner_guid,
    END OF ty_but000,

    BEGIN OF ty_tickets,
      guid      TYPE crmt_object_guid,
      object_id TYPE crmt_object_id,
    END OF ty_tickets,

    BEGIN OF ty_ibint,
      instance TYPE ib_instance,
      descr    TYPE ib_inst_descr,
    END OF ty_ibint.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <f_guid>         TYPE crmt_object_guid,
                 <f_result>       TYPE znasm_workorders,
                 <f_items_result> TYPE znasm_workorderitems,
                 <f_data>         TYPE any,
                 <f_but000>       TYPE ty_but000,
                 <f_ticket>       TYPE ty_tickets,
                 <f_ibint>        TYPE ty_ibint.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS:     <f_orderadm_h>  TYPE  crmt_orderadm_h_wrk,
                     <f_orderadm_i>  TYPE  crmt_orderadm_i_wrk,
                     <f_higher_item> TYPE  crmt_orderadm_i_wrk,
                     <f_sales>       TYPE  crmt_sales_wrk,
                     <f_customer_h>  TYPE  crmt_customer_h_wrk,
                     <f_customer_i>  TYPE  crmt_customer_i_wrk,
                     <f_appointment> TYPE  crmt_appointment_wrk,
                     <f_text>        TYPE  crmt_text_wrk,
                     <f_lines>       TYPE tline,
                     <f_schedlin>    TYPE  crmt_schedlin_wrk,
                     <f_partner>     TYPE  crmt_partner_external_wrk,
                     <f_service_os>  TYPE  crmt_srv_osset_wrk,
                     <f_refobj>      TYPE  crmt_refobj_wrk,
                     <f_status>      TYPE  crmt_status_wrk,
                     <f_status_h>    TYPE  crmt_status_h_wrk,
                     <f_schedlin_i>  TYPE  crmt_schedlin_i_wrk,
                     <f_doc_flow>    TYPE  crmt_doc_flow_wrk.

  DATA:
    lt_status_filter     TYPE        rsdsselopt_t,
    ls_status_filter     TYPE        rsdsselopt,
    lt_header_guids      TYPE        crmt_object_guid_tab,
    lt_requested_objects TYPE        crmt_object_name_tab,
    lr_dref              TYPE REF TO data,
    lv_log_handle        TYPE        balloghndl,
    lv_or_flag           TYPE        boolean,
    lv_cnt               TYPE        i,
    lt_attachments       TYPE        zsm_attachments_tab,
    ls_attachments       TYPE        zsm_attachments.


  DATA:
    lt_ibint       TYPE TABLE OF ty_ibint,
    lt_but000      TYPE TABLE OF ty_but000,
    lt_tickets     TYPE TABLE OF ty_tickets,
    lt_orderadm_h  TYPE  crmt_orderadm_h_wrkt,
    lt_opport_h    TYPE  crmt_opport_h_wrkt,
    lt_orderadm_i  TYPE  crmt_orderadm_i_wrkt,
    lt_sales       TYPE  crmt_sales_wrkt,
    lt_customer_h  TYPE  crmt_customer_h_wrkt,
    lt_customer_i  TYPE  crmt_customer_i_wrkt,
    lt_appointment TYPE  crmt_appointment_wrkt,
    lt_text        TYPE  crmt_text_wrkt,
    lt_schedlin    TYPE  crmt_schedlin_wrkt,
    lt_partner     TYPE  crmt_partner_external_wrkt,
    lt_shipto      TYPE  crmt_partner_external_wrkt,
    lt_refobj      TYPE  crmt_refobj_wrkt,
    lt_status      TYPE  crmt_status_wrkt,
    lt_status_temp TYPE  crmt_status_wrkt,
    lt_schedlin_i  TYPE  crmt_schedlin_i_wrkt,
    lt_doc_flow    TYPE  crmt_doc_flow_wrkt.


*-----------------------------------------------------------
  " Create the filter query
*-----------------------------------------------------------
  lr_core = cl_crm_bol_core=>get_instance( ).
  lr_core->load_component_set( 'ONEORDER' ).

  CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT'
    EXPORTING
      input  = iv_ship_to
    IMPORTING
      output = iv_ship_to.
*Get and prepare dynamic query service.
  lr_qs ?= cl_crm_bol_dquery_service=>get_instance( 'BTQSrvOrd' ).

  IF lr_qs IS NOT INITIAL.
*build object id query
    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING it_order
                                         'OBJECT_ID'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                         lv_query_exists.

***status query build
    lt_status_filter = it_status.

* Filter on open and in progress orders
    IF it_status IS INITIAL." 
      MOVE 'E0002ZRPM_H' TO ls_status_filter-low.  "Pending Customer
      MOVE 'I' TO ls_status_filter-sign.
      MOVE 'EQ' TO ls_status_filter-option.
      APPEND ls_status_filter TO lt_status_filter.

      MOVE 'E0003ZRPM_H' TO ls_status_filter-low.  "Requires Approval
      MOVE 'I' TO ls_status_filter-sign.
      MOVE 'EQ' TO ls_status_filter-option.
      APPEND ls_status_filter TO lt_status_filter.

      MOVE 'E0009ZRPM_H' TO ls_status_filter-low.  "PM In Progress
      MOVE 'I' TO ls_status_filter-sign.
      MOVE 'EQ' TO ls_status_filter-option.
      APPEND ls_status_filter TO lt_status_filter.
    ENDIF.

    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING lt_status_filter
                                         'STATUS_COMMON'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                         lv_query_exists.

*date query build
    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING it_date_range
                                         'POSTING_DATE' "'DATE_RANGE'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                         lv_query_exists.


*build ship to party queries
    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING it_ship_to
                                         'BU_PARTNER'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                         lv_query_exists.
    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING it_sold_to
                                         'SOLD_TO_PARTY'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                  lv_query_exists.


*build assigned to  queries
    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING it_assigned_to
                                         'CREATED_BY'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                  lv_query_exists.
    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING it_territory
                                         'SERVICE_ORG'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                  lv_query_exists.
    PERFORM add_to_selection_param USING it_process_type
                                         'PROCESS_TYPE'
                                CHANGING lr_qs
                                  lv_query_exists.

  ELSE.
    RETURN.
  ENDIF.
  CHECK lv_query_exists EQ abap_true.

* Set Query Parameters.
  IF iv_max_hits IS NOT INITIAL.
    ls_param-name = 'MAX_HITS'.
    ls_param-value = iv_max_hits.
    APPEND ls_param TO lt_param.
  ENDIF.
  lr_qs->set_query_parameters( lt_param ).
 lr_qs->ADD_SELECTION_PARAM( iv_attr_name = 'CHANGED_AT'
 iv_sign = 'I'
iv_option = 'GT'
iv_low = '20171127000000' ).

*Execute Query and retrieve result
  lr_result = lr_qs->get_query_result( ).
*
  CHECK lr_result IS BOUND.
*Use Iterator to access entities in query result
  lr_iter ?= lr_result->get_iterator( ).
*
* Get the first record from Collection.
  lr_entity = lr_iter->get_first( ).

  WHILE lr_entity IS BOUND.
*Access Attributes of Business object.
*    lv_object_id_fm = lr_entity->get_property_as_string( 'OBJECT_ID' ).
    IF ( lr_entity->get_property_as_string( 'CONCATSTATUSER' ) EQ 'PM Complete'
      OR lr_entity->get_property_as_string( 'CONCATSTATUSER' ) EQ 'Cancelled' )."  and ( sy-uname ne 'HASAXENA.EXT' ).
      lr_entity = lr_iter->get_next( ).
      CONTINUE.
    ENDIF.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'GUID' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_guid>.
    INSERT <f_guid> INTO TABLE lt_header_guids.
    APPEND INITIAL LINE TO et_result ASSIGNING <f_result>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'OBJECT_ID' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-workorder = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'SOLD_TO_PARTY' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-kunnr = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'CONTACT_PERSON' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-contact = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'SOLD_TO_PARTY_LIST' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-sold_party_name = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'NET_VALUE' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-price = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'PROCESS_TYPE' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-type = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'CREATED_BY' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-assignedto = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'SERVICE_ORG' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-territory = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'PO_NUMBER_SOLD' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-customer_po = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'VALID_FROM' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-startdate = <f_data>.
    lr_dref = lr_entity->get_property( 'VALID_TO' ).
    ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <f_data>.
    <f_result>-enddate = <f_data>.

    lr_entity = lr_iter->get_next( ).
  ENDWHILE.


*-----------------------------------------------------------
  " Read additional data for result list
*-----------------------------------------------------------
  IF lt_header_guids IS NOT INITIAL.
* fill internal tables
    INSERT gc_object_name-orderadm_h INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-orderadm_i  INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-status      INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-partner     INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-doc_flow    INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-refobj      INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-schedlin    INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-schedlin_i  INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-appointment INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-texts       INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-sales       INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-customer_i  INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.
    INSERT gc_object_name-customer_h  INTO TABLE lt_requested_objects.

    CALL FUNCTION 'CRM_ORDER_READ'
      EXPORTING
        it_header_guid       = lt_header_guids
        iv_mode              = 'C'
        it_requested_objects = lt_requested_objects
        iv_only_spec_items   = iv_header_only
        iv_no_auth_check     = 'X'
      IMPORTING
        et_orderadm_h        = lt_orderadm_h
        et_orderadm_i        = lt_orderadm_i
        et_sales             = lt_sales
        et_customer_h        = lt_customer_h
        et_customer_i        = lt_customer_i
        et_appointment       = lt_appointment
        et_text              = lt_text
        et_schedlin          = lt_schedlin
        et_partner           = lt_partner
        et_refobj            = lt_refobj
        et_status            = lt_status
        et_schedlin_i        = lt_schedlin_i
        et_doc_flow          = lt_doc_flow
      CHANGING
        cv_log_handle        = lv_log_handle
      EXCEPTIONS
        document_not_found   = 1
        error_occurred       = 2
        document_locked      = 3
        no_change_authority  = 4
        no_display_authority = 5
        no_change_allowed    = 6
        OTHERS               = 7.

  ENDIF.

FORM add_to_selection_param  USING    p_selopt TYPE rsdsselopt_t
                                      VALUE(p_attr_name)
                             CHANGING lr_qs TYPE REF TO cl_crm_bol_dquery_service
                                      p_query_exists TYPE boolean.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <f_selopt> TYPE rsdsselopt.
  DATA: lv_low  TYPE string,
        lv_high TYPE string.


  LOOP AT p_selopt ASSIGNING <f_selopt>.
    IF <f_selopt>-low IS NOT INITIAL.
      lv_low = <f_selopt>-low.
      lv_high = <f_selopt>-high.
* *Add selected parameters or criteria .
      lr_qs->add_selection_param( iv_attr_name = p_attr_name
                                   iv_sign = <f_selopt>-sign
                                   iv_low  = lv_low
                                   iv_option = <f_selopt>-option
                                   iv_high = lv_high ).
      p_query_exists = abap_true.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.

ENDFORM.
```

Comment: Give the full code with all data declarations.

Comment: Added the complete code

Comment: Plenty of declarations but no relevant ones:) Where is  `lr_qs`, `lr_core` `it_status` are declared? Where is the implementation of `add_to_selection_param` subroutine? Read about [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please ignore the irrelevant data declarations...added the sub routine...

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the Date Format of your User is relevant. You will find this settings in SU3 - Defaults

Comment: @MichaelMeyer - it is not related user date format

Comment: ok, I see. Did you try to execute your query in the GENIL_BOL_BROWSER?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer Yes, but this field query didn't work in browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of the data type?

instead of

```
  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <f_selopt> TYPE rsdsselopt.
  DATA: lv_low  TYPE string,
        lv_high TYPE string.
```

maybe try

```
  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <f_selopt> TYPE rsdsselopt.
  DATA: lv_low  TYPE comt_changed_at_usr,
        lv_high TYPE comt_changed_at_usr.
```